# Security considerations with using an NTP server

Tags: security, ntp

What are the security considerations to keep in mind when using an [NTP server](http://www.ntp.org/) to synchronize time? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) lists that there are no known high-risk vulnerabilities, but are there any lower risk weak points one should be aware of?

Also, are there any special concerns when using [NTP pool servers](http://www.pool.ntp.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Paper](http://www.giac.org/practical/Matt_Willman_GSEC.doc) written for GIAC qualification with in depth analysis of NTP security.

An [overview](http://www.streetdirectory.com/travel_guide/119397/security/ntp_security_authentication_and_trusted_time_references.html) of NTP that's a little less verbose.

> NTP is therefore vulnerable to security threats, whether from a malicious hacker who wants to alter the timestamp to commit fraud or a DDoS attack (Distributed Denial of Service - normally caused by malicious malware that floods a server with traffic) that blocks server access.

With regards to the pool servers, please remember they're [volunteered](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/NTPPoolServers) servers.

From what I've read in the past, unless you have time critical tasks the highest risk is DDOS.

Comment: I would think the DDOS would affect the NTP server itself, not the server synching to the NTP server.

Comment: http://www.cis.udel.edu/~mills/database/brief/autokey/autokey.ppt

Mills is the original author for NTP.  In his powerpoint he specifies that

- An intruder can generate packets faster than the server, network or client can process them, especially if they require expensive cryptographic computations.